# What is this item in Sheldon and Leonard's apartment?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

What is this device on the table right of the couch (where Sheldon typically sits)?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's a "*[V-Tech Retro Cordless Phone with Digital Answering System and Speakerphone](http://www.mdxelectronics.com/LS6195.html)*". specifically the LS6195.

[image]

This was a product placement by [Entertainment Services](http://entertainmentservices.net/photoGallery.php#73). The show featured a [range](http://entertainmentservices.net/photoGallery.php#58) of VTech [products](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kd1s/4013517480) over its 12 seasons.

[image]